# How can I use a variable that has been initialized in a when-expression?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to initialize `copyToDay` in a when-expression to get the specific day string, but how can I use it any further? I need the right string in a following function, but Android Studio says `copyToDay` hasn't been initialized.
Here's my code:

```
    val onCheckListener = View.OnClickListener {
        it as CheckedTextView
        it.isChecked = !it.isChecked

        when(it){
            copyHoursMonday -> copyToDay = R.string.MONDAY
            copyHoursTuesday -> copyToDay = R.string.TUESDAY
            copyHoursWednesday -> copyToDay = R.string.WEDNESDAY
            copyHoursThursday -> copyToDay = R.string.THURSDAY
            copyHoursFriday -> copyToDay = R.string.FRIDAY
            copyHoursSaturday -> copyToDay = R.string.SATURDAY
            copyHoursSunday -> copyToDay = R.string.SUNDAY
            }
            //Here's the error with copyToDay
            saveCopy(initialStartInMinutes, initialEndInMinutes, isHappyHour, d, copyToDay)
        }

    d.copyHoursMonday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursTuesday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursWednesday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursThursday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursFriday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursSaturday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
    d.copyHoursSunday.setOnClickListener(onCheckListener)
```

Is there some way to get copyToDay from the when-expression?
Thanks for for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `else` branch in your `when` statement. That way the compiler knows that your variable has been initialised in every possible branch.
For example:

```
      when(it){
        copyHoursMonday -> copyToDay = R.string.MONDAY
        copyHoursTuesday -> copyToDay = R.string.TUESDAY
        copyHoursWednesday -> copyToDay = R.string.WEDNESDAY
        copyHoursThursday -> copyToDay = R.string.THURSDAY
        copyHoursFriday -> copyToDay = R.string.FRIDAY
        copyHoursSaturday -> copyToDay = R.string.SATURDAY
        else -> copyToDay = R.string.SUNDAY
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a scope issue. The variable might not have been initialized. `it` is, in this case, the view you're using. Now, before I continue, I want to mention one thing: The compiler doesn't know whether or not you set that click listener for multiple views or not. As a result, the compiler thinks "If this is any other view, it will not be initialized".

What you can do, is adding an `else` to the `when`:

```
else -> return@OnClickListener;
```

This means, in any other case, it returns. It doesn't execute the code that depends on the value, and it also won't be initialized.

Alternatively, you can assign a different value in the else brach. Either is fine.

Also, you can optimize your when statement. Since you assign the same value on every branch, you can simply do:

```
val copyToDay = when(it){
    copyHoursMonday -> R.string.MONDAY
    copyHoursTuesday -> R.string.TUESDAY
    copyHoursWednesday -> R.string.WEDNESDAY
    copyHoursThursday -> R.string.THURSDAY
    copyHoursFriday -> R.string.FRIDAY
    copyHoursSaturday -> R.string.SATURDAY
    copyHoursSunday -> R.string.SUNDAY
    else -> return@OnClickListener
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `when` as an expression:

```
val copyToDay = when(it){
    copyHoursMonday -> R.string.MONDAY
    copyHoursTuesday -> R.string.TUESDAY
    //...
}
```

Comment: `copyHoursSunday` is a View, not an enum. While this would work if the statement was exhaustive, there's still a chance the view passed is none of those. So there's still a tiny chance it's not initialized, which the compiler complains about

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is saying its not initialised is because when your code run if **it** variable is **true**  copyToDay variable will be initialised..but if **it** is false copyToDay will not be initialised.
Hence you need to cater for the false scenario.The best is to give it a default value just above the **when(it){}**